# How does one provide default parameters in Javascript anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript, web, closures, anonymous-function, default-parameters

I am new to JS and I need to use an anonymous function, but when I provide default values to parameters as in named functions, I get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =".

Here's the code excerpt:

```
//some properties
initResize: function(isPlayerInitializing=true){ 
    //some execution
},
//some more properties
```

I would like to know how one would provide default values to parameters of anonymous functions in Javascript.

Comment: My guess is you are not running a browser that supports it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all [browsers support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility) that syntax so you need to do it the old school way

```
initResize: function(isPlayerInitializing){ 
    if (isPlayerInitializing===undefined) {
        isPlayerInitializing = true;
    }
    //some execution
},
```

Answer (score 0):

or the Javascript shortcut way

```
initResize: function(isPlayerInitializing){ 
    isPlayerInitializing = isPlayerInitialing || true;
    //some execution
},
```